# Get first route parameter in service

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-services

I would like to have a service, that have an observable with a variable dependant of current URL.

```
:programID                  --  program overivew
:programID/bug              --  bug list
:programID/bug/:bugID       --  bug overview
```

Where `programID` may switch at any point. I have made a service, that from what I understood from [angular docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html), should make an observable with parameters

ProgramService: (extract)

```js
currentProgramID: number

constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private http: Http){

    this.route.params.subscribe((params: Params) => {
        console.log('Parent:', params['programID'])
    })

    this.route.children[0].params.subscribe((params: Params) => {
        console.log('Childern:', params['programID'])
        //  Works if loaded while at url : 'abc123/bug/abc123'
    })

    this.route.params.subscribe((params: Params) => {
        console.log('Hacky?:', this.route.snapshot.params['programID'])
    })
}
```

Components, that need current program reference: (extract)

```js
program: Promise<program>

constructor(
    private programService: ProgramService, ... ){}

ngOnInit() {
    this.program = this.programService.getProgram(/*current program*/)
    ...
}
```

However I only get the `programID` once, and that when the page is loaded at correct URL. I don't even get if after navigating.

Afterwards I will switch to `switchMap` but for testing purposes, this was more in place.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `router.events` and `router.routerState.snapshot.root.firstChild` to read the `params`:

```ts
@Injectable()
class ProgramService {
  programId:string;
  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    //private http: Http
    ){

    this.router.events
    .filter(e => e instanceof NavigationEnd)
    .forEach(e =>{
      var firstChild = router.currentRouterState.snapshot.root.firstChild;
      console.log(firstChild.params);
      console.log(firstChild.firstChild && firstChild.firstChild.firstChild && firstChild.firstChild.firstChild.params);
      var newProgramId = firstChild.params['programID'];
      if(this.programId != newProgramId) {
        this.programId = newProgramId;
        this.programService.getProgram(this.programId);
      }
    });
```

[**Plunker example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/pd5qbLUh27KeNqZgB9Zx?p=preview)

Comment: That is true, but why don't the observable don't fire up? And is adding the Params manually only option?

Comment: The service is only created once. Routed components are created every time the app navigates to the route for this component. This is why the service gets the `ActivatedRoute` only injected once. The next time you navigate to this route there is a new `ActivatedRoute` instance created, but the service still holds the old one (except when the service is provided in `@Component()` of the routed component, this is why the observable doesn't fire, because it's stale.

Comment: Alternatively you can inject the service to routed components and make the components pass the parameters to the service instead of the service acquiring it by itself. I don't have deep knowledge about the router, there might be other ways I'm not aware of.

Comment: I added a currentProgramID parameter, what was the original point of doing it, as well as not needing activeRoute in every component...

Comment: What did I subscribed to then, if it ain't params changes...?

Comment: If you pass `ActivatedRoute` to a component, and you change the route so that **only** parameter values change, then this will emit a new value. If you navigate to a different route, the component will be destroyed and therefore also the subscription. This is the only use case where this is useful, because `ngOnInit()` and the constructor are not called again in this situation because the component instance is reused.

Comment: First thing, don't use `currentRouterState`, but `routerState`, as `currentRouterState` is private. And second, the problem is, that it won't fire before `ngOnInit`... any fix?

Comment: I see. I use TS only in Plunker and there I don't get this information. I don't think the "fire" is in any way related to lifecycle methods like `ngOnInit()`. It fires after a route change happened. Why is that a problem?

Comment: It was supposed to fetch `programID` variable before any routed components would get chance to get the old one. There are ways to patch fix it, but is there a correct way to approach this?

Comment: Sorry, don't understand what you mean with " fetch programID variable before any routed components would get chance to get the old one." Can you please add the code to your question that demonstrates what you try to accomplish?

Comment: Just move the code from `ngOnInit()` into `subscribe()` - see my updated answer.

Comment: There isn't any subscribe anywhere, do I miss something?

Comment: Sorry, I used `forEach()` in my answer, it's similar, you can also use `subscribe()` instead of `forEach()`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134991/discussion-between-akxe-and-gunter-zochbauer).